# What is the name of this game with a silver-haired elf-like character?

Tags: game-identification

There is a game featured on [this YouTube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCmWKwaBitVqivIcbqdopbwg), in all four videos.
If anyone can tell me what the name of the game is (or the name of the character in those videos) I'd be really grateful.

Here are some screenshots taken from the videos:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 19):

This is Mabinogi, a fantasy life MMORPG.
https://mabinogi.nexon.net/landing/

Comment: Looks correct: https://wiki.mabinogiworld.com/view/Lyre